# Service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I want to create a container service so I do using classe with a contructor :

service.xml :

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<parameters>
    <parameter key="myapp_mybundle.locationmanager.class">My_app\MyBundle\Manager\LocationManager</parameter>
    <parameter key="myapp_mybundle.rootLocation">rootLocation</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="myapp_mybundle.locationmanager" class="%myapp_mybundle.locationmanager.class%">
    <argument>%myapp_mybundle.rootLocation%</argument>

    </service>
</services>
```

MyappMyBundleExtension.php

```
$container->set('myapp_mybundle.locationmanager', $manager);
```

class locationManager :

```
class LocationManager
{
     /**
     * @var Location
     */
protected $rootLocation;

public function __construct(Location $rootLocation)
{
    $this->rootLocation = $rootLocation;
}
   .....
```

and  some action in controller :

```
   $locationManager =  $this->container->get("myapp_mybundle.locationmanager");
```

I get this error :

```
  You have requested a non-existent service "myapp_mybundle.locationmanager".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually load the services.xml file?

Like such:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

If you don't do that, you're services are not injected into the container and you won't be able to load them.

More info about this can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Comment: And what happens if you debug the container in the console with `php app/console container:debug`?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the entire `MyAppMyBundleExtension` class? I think the issue is in there...

Answer (score 0):

Your service doesn't have an uppercase "b"... should be

`$locationManager =  $this->container->get("myapp_mybundle.locationmanager");`

Comment: No it's just an error when i write my message,I know but it's not here the problem,so any other solution please?